# Installed update and VS 2012 doesnt open azure project anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure

Yesterday I installed a bunch of updates, none specific to the visual studio 2012 sp1 (but I did installed the .Net 4.5.1), and restarted the pc... after that my azure Web/Worker Role projects don't load anymore (the others projects in the solution loads, but the project where I, for example, set the number of instances etc, no deal)... can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing a package (any azure package) from Web Installer and it restored everything... prob was a missing dll or something...